# fetch two images in cloudinary and overlay each on the other

Tags: image, api, http, url, cloudinary

I found how to overlay two already uploaded cloudinary images through the below query

http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/w_400,h_250,c_fill,g_south/l_nice_couple,w_90,g_center,y_18,x_-20/coffee_cup.jpg

this is image 
[image]

if we stripdown the above query the format is

```
http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/
w_400,h_250,c_fill,g_south/
l_
nice_couple,
w_90,g_center,y_18,x_-20/
coffee_cup.jpg
```

in the above `nice_couple` is the one which going to overlay on top of the  `coffee_cup.jpg`.

What i want is that **both images** which i am using overlaying mechanism has to be **fetched from another url.**

```
http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/fetch/
w_400,h_250,c_fill,g_south/
l_
nice_couple,
w_90,g_center,y_18,x_-20/
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/35/Sachin_at_Castrol_Golden_Spanner_Awards_%28crop%29.jpg.jpg
```

i was able s**uccessfully fetched one image** in the overlaying mechanism through the above query. But if i try to change the `nice_couple` **image to another fetching url it's not working**

```
http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/fetch/
w_400,h_250,c_fill,g_south/
l_
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0c/Scarlett_Johansson_Césars_2014.jpg,
w_90,g_center,y_18,x_-20/
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/35/Sachin_at_Castrol_Golden_Spanner_Awards_%28crop%29.jpg.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an already pending feature request at Cloudinary.
At the meantime you can try to use [auto-upload](http://cloudinary.com/blog/how_to_automatically_migrate_all_your_images_to_the_cloud) to have the overlay image **lazily** uploaded to your account when used within the transformation. For example:
mapping the `"remote_media/"` folder to `"http://upload.wikimedia.org/ wikipedia/commons/"` will allow you to use the following URL:
[http://res.cloudinary.com/dcd0vnhxd/image/fetch/l_upload:remote_media:0:0c:Scarlett_Johansson_Césars_2014.jpg,w_30/remote_media/4/46/Jennifer_Lawrence_at_the_83rd_Academy_Awards.jpg](http://res.cloudinary.com/dcd0vnhxd/image/fetch/l_upload:remote_media:0:0c:Scarlett_Johansson_C%C3%A9sars_2014.jpg,w_30/remote_media/4/46/Jennifer_Lawrence_at_the_83rd_Academy_Awards.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Currently the "fetch" feature is supported for the main image only, not for overlays/underlays.